# A question about order of convergence

Tags: solution-verification, rate-of-convergence

If given the iterative method:

$$x_{n+1}=e^{x_n x_{n-1}}-1$$

we need to find the rate of convergence if given that it converges to zero.

can I do the following:

$$x_{n+1}+1=e^{x_n x_{n-1}}$$

$$\ln(x_{n+1}+1)=\ln(e^{x_n x_{n-1}})$$

$${x_n x_{n-1}}=\ln(x_{n+1}+1)$$

$${x_n}={\varepsilon_n} +c$$ where c is zero.

and then with the help of Taylor series:

$$\ln(\varepsilon_{n+1}+1)= \ln(1)+{\varepsilon_{n+1}}\ln'(1)+...∼ \varepsilon_{n+1}$$

then I can get that:

$$\varepsilon_{n+1} ∼ {\varepsilon_{n}} {\varepsilon_{n-1}}$$

for all n we define $$|\varepsilon_n|=\delta_n$$ and then we get $$(1) \delta_{k+1}∼|A|\delta_{k}\delta_{k-1}$$
then we define m=rate and guess
$$\delta_{n+1}∼\lambda \delta_{n}^m$$ for $$\lambda>0$$ and $$1 \le m \le 2$$
and then we substitute n= k-1, k and get
$$\delta_{k+1}∼\lambda \delta_{k}^m, \delta_{k}∼\lambda \delta_{k-1}^m$$
$$\delta_{k+1}∼\lambda \delta_{k}^m∼\lambda(\lambda\delta_{k-1}^m)^m=\lambda^{m+1}\delta_{k-1}^{m^2}$$
then we substitute in (1) and get $$\lambda^{m+1}\delta_{k-1}^{m^2}∼|A|(\lambda\delta_{k-1})\delta_{k-1}$$ we can pick $$\lambda=|A|^\frac{1}{m}$$
$$\lambda^{m+1}\delta_{k-1}^{m^2}∼\lambda^m(\lambda \delta_{k-1}^{m})\delta_{k-1}$$
$$\delta_{k-1}^{m^2}∼\delta_{k-1}^{m+1}$$
then we just solve $$m^2=m+1$$ and get $$m=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $$

Comment: I meant $$ \frac{1+ \sqrt{5} }{2}$$

Comment: I know how to find the rate after I get to that point. I just wanna make sure I started right and got that equation (εn+1≈εnεn−1) with the right steps

Comment: $x_{n+1}\sim x_nx_{n-1}$ is correct (no need to rename $x$ to $\varepsilon$ and better use the [meaningful symbol $\sim$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)), and can be obtained much more quickly: simply use that as $u\to0,$ $e^u-1\sim u.$ But now you are talking about the *rate* and not of the *order*. Again, can you please include its general definition, and how you "know how to find" the golden ratio?

Comment: I did, I'm not really used to writing these things so it takes me a lot of time. But here it is it's exactly the way I learned it I took that part that I added from my lecture.

Comment: Thank you *very much*!This does not prove the *existence* of the *order* of convergence of your sequence but the rest is fine. Since your question was only about the correctness of your proof of $x_{n+1}\sim x_nx_{n-1},$ I think the question can be closed, don't you? p.s. Small remark: in "$\ln(\varepsilon_{n+1}+1)∼ \ln(1)+{\varepsilon_{n+1}}\ln'(1)+...∼ 0+\varepsilon_{n+1}$", the first $\sim$ should be an $=$ (because of the $\dots$) and there should be no $0$ after the second $\sim$ ($\sim$ is not additive).

Comment: thank you. But what do you mean by "This does not prove the existence of the order of convergence of your sequence"? I was just asked to find the order of convergence given that it converges, so what I've done is not enough?

Comment: What I mean is that you do not merely assume it converges: you assume moreover that it has an order of convergence, i.e. that $\delta_{n+1}∼\lambda \delta_{n}^m$ for some $\lambda,m$ (and you determine $m$ under this assumption). But I have no idea how one could prove it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot!